# Assembly x86 (NASM) - Comparing a String Char by char

Tags: assembly, x86-64, nasm

for a Project at University I need to make small Assembly programs.
And for one of those I need to check if the arguments are palindromes. (abba = palindrome / acba = no palindrome)

I have nearly everything but I kind of have a problem with comparing. I planed to have the string in rsi and rax. Then move with `inc rsi` from one side and with `dec rax` from the other side comparing in each step the characters.

But I think that somehow my rax is empty or the `add rax, rdx` doesnt put the Pointer at the end of the string.

```
eos_found:
    pop rsi     ; restore starting address of string
    push rdx    ; store length of string
    push rsi
    push rsi
    pop rax

    add rax, rdx ;pointer points to the end of the string   

cmp_strings:
    cmp [rsi], byte 0
    je is_palindrome

    mov al, [rax]
    cmp [rsi], al
    jne not_palindrome

    inc rsi
    dec rax
    jmp cmp_strings
```

Comment: `al` is  a part of `rax`. So, `mov al, [rax]` does not only change `al` but also `rax`.

Comment: rax is a 64 bit register. al is simply the lowest byte of rax. You are overwriting rax in this instruction *mov al, [rax]*. Maybe use bl here :). The instruction would look like this then: *mov bl,[rax]*, followed by *cmp [rsi],bl*